# Bluetooth Appearance Icons

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm working on firmware for a BLE device and need to define an **appearance** value. For now, I have chosen a 'Generic Computer'. However, the full list of appearance values https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.appearance.xml
has some values that might be more appropriate. In Windows 10 the 'Generic Computer' shows up with an icon of a desktop PC. Is there a resource available that will allow me to view the icons for any/all of the supported appearance values? I'd like to avoid multiple compile, load and browse cycles just to observe the icons.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer to this question I can find is that:

1. The specification only assigns a general description to different values (e.g. "generic phone" or "generic thermometer". The official mapping can be found at [bluetooth.com](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.appearance.xml).
2. The actual icons (and perhaps any extensions) are vendor-specific. I have yet to find a search result that shows all icons for a particular implementation.

Comment: It seems that the specs have moved to a YAML file stored at BitBucket https://bitbucket.org/bluetooth-SIG/public/src/main/assigned_numbers/core/appearance_values.yaml (you get that link when searching for "assigned numbers for appearance values" on the bluetooth.com website). This link is almost certain to break in the near  future (since Atlassian's support of BitBucket is shaky at best, and can get discontinued in the near future...)

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn  well, you could always use the actual spec from Bluetooth SIG  https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Files/Specification/Assigned_Numbers.html#bookmark49 .... at least until they break it as they often do